# Irreducibility of polynomials in $\mathbf{Z}_p[x]$ - understanding proofs

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials

I am reading through some irreducibility proofs and there's something I don't quite understand:

- $x^3+2x+1$ is irreducible in $\mathbf{Z}_3[x]:$ no roots in $\mathbf{Z}_3$ and degree $3$ so irreducible.
- $x^5+x^2+1$ is irreducible in $\mathbf{Z}_2[x]:$ no roots in $\mathbf{Z}_2$ so suffices to show it has no quadratic factors. The only quadratic in $\mathbf{Z}_2[x]$ without roots in $\mathbf{Z}_2$ is $x^2+x+1$ which does not divide the polynomial, so done.

I'm confused as to why the second case requires more work, or equivalently why the first requires less? Why do we not need to check quadratic factors in the first case, or why is the degree of the latter being odd not enough?

Comment: Here's a relevant comparison. For a polynomial to be irreducible means the same thing as for an integer to be a prime. And usually you need to work harder to check that a five digit number is a prime in comparison to the amount of checking needed to verify that a three digit integer is a prime. Substitute: prime -> irreducible, number of digits -> degree, and your surprise should go away. Over a finite field $\Bbb{F}_q$ the analogy can be made surprisingly precise! Particularly if you would think of "digits" in base $q$.

Comment: Continuing the analogy: checking the absence of zeros in the base field is thus about as informative as checking whether a candidate prime number is divisible by any of the single digit primes (2,3,5,7). That is, the beginning of a sieve, but not much more.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks, that's a nice way of thinking about it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For a polynomial of degree $3$, if it's not irreducible then it must split in factors that have degree $2$ or $1$, and there must be a factor of degree $1$ (so a root). Hence it suffices to check that there are roots.

In degree $5$, your polynomial can split in two factors of respective degree $2$ and $3$ : so you can be reducible without having roots.

Comment: Ah of course. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

"Reducible" is not synonim of "has a root". A polynomial can be reducible on a given field without having roots in that field, like the polynomial
$$
p(x)=x^4+2 x^2+1= (x^2+1)\cdot(x^2+1),
$$
which by sure has no real roots. In other words having a root $x_0$ is equivalent to say that the polynomial is reducible *and* one factor has *degree one*, that is $(x-x_0)$. So you understand why in the case of degree equal three the two concepts are equivalent: any decomposition gives you a product of a degree one polynom by a degree two polynom.